# Drone wobble/bounce while flying

Tags: troubleshooting

I recently gave my newly built (with old equipment) its first flight. As you can see throughout the video there is a wobble as I fly.

https://youtu.be/foo7Tw1gYNY

I am running an SP Neo F3 FC with Cleanflight on a QAV-X Charpu frame.

Just wondering if any of you know what are some of the things I should look for that might cause this.

Edit: I re-calibrated the accelerometer which was a bit out, but still experienced the wobble.

Answer (score 5):

Try lowering your $D$ coefficients by $10$ in each direction. If that doesn’t help, *slowly* try increasing your $I$ coefficients.

[Make sure you first implement (and *TEST!*) a kill switch any time you are modifying PID terms (particularly $I$ terms) as you can create an unrecoverable flyaway situation!]